# How to get parent node?

Tags: xpath

```
//* [ local-name()='component' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'   ]
```

Using thispath, I can get a node like this：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<component>
    <structuredBody> 
      <component>
          <section>
          <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
          <title>History of Present Illness</title>
          <text>
          </text>
          </section>
      </component>
    <component>     ......      </component>
    <component>     ......      </component>
</structuredBody>
</component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

In order to get the node as below:

```
<component>
        <section>
        <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
        <title>History of Present Illness</title>
        <text>
        </text>
        </section>
    </component>
```

I  change the path to :

```
//* [ local-name()='component' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'  and  position()=1]
```

But, how can I get the same result by using `[code="10164-2"]` as a qualification?

edit 2012-12-17

> //:component[1]//:component[.//:section/:code[@code='10164-2']]

this xpath works well and I can get the node I want  . What should I do If I use

> //*[local-name()='component' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'])[1]

to select the parent `<component/>`node then add  [@code='10164-2'] to the predicate part  to get the `<component/>`child node i want. (I would like not to use  : in the path to avoid namespace issue)

Comment: Dimitre novatchev .  Thanks for your answer .      May I  see it tomorrow, as today I have to finish my report and send it to my professor first.  I will try to use your solution and reply to you then.

Comment: ok , I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
      ((//*[local-name()='component'
         and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
       )[1]
          //*[local-name()='component'
            and
              namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'
             ]
      )[1]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "((//*[local-name()='component'
         and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
     )[1]
        //*[local-name()='component'
            and
              namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
     )[1]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <structuredBody>
      <component>
          <section>
          <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
          <title>History of Present Illness</title>
          <text>
          </text>
          </section>
      </component>
    <component>     ......      </component>
    <component>     ......      </component>
</structuredBody>
</component>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the results of this evaluation are copied to the output:**

```
<component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
   <section>
      <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
      <title>History of Present Illness</title>
      <text/>
   </section>
</component>
```

Comment: @chris.shi, In order for you to receive any useful answer at all, you need to show us the XML document --complete, but as small as possible, against which the XPath expression is to be evaluated, and to specify exactly which node(s) is/are to be selected. Without this important information people cannot reproduce your problem and any XPath expression they give you maynot select the wanted node(s) when evaluated on an XML document they have never seen.

Comment: @chris.shi, I have updated the answer and have verified that the new XPath expression selects the `component` element that you want. Please, try it.

Comment: thanks for your great help . also i have updated the xml document to complete structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `and section/code/@code='10164-2'` to your predicate:

```
//*:component[namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3' and section/code/@code='10164-2']
```

Note: You may have to remove `namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'` if `component` isn't in that namespace. Your example in "*in order to get the node as below:*" does not have a namespace.

Also, I used `*:component` instead of `local-name()` since you tagged the question XPath 2.0.

Comment: Daniel Haley .  thanks for your help. I will try to use your solution and reply to you then.

Comment: Daniel Haley. this  xml document has a default namespace of urn:hl7-org:v3.    //*:component[namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3' and section/code/@code='10164-2']  I tried to use it and exception of [javax.xml.transform.transformerexception extra illegal tokens] was threw out. then I changed the path to   //* [ local-name()='component' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'   and section/code/@code='10164-2'] , but no node returned.